# How to get CBitmap from IStream available

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, wpd

I am working with WPD (Windows Portable Devices) API, and I have a problem. I have obtained image, video, music objects list on a device, and now I want to get thumbnail of images. I have used the following to get Stream of image objects:

```
spPropertyKeys->Add(WPD_RESOURCE_THUMBNAIL);
```

and then get stream by:

```
hr = pd_resource->GetStream(objectID,WPD_RESOURCE_THUMBNAIL, STGM_READ, &optimal_transfer_size, &src_data_stream);
```

output is src_data_stream.

I want to know that above the way to retrieve images's thumbnail is a true idea? How do I convert this stream to CBitmap?
Please help me! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If this stream is a bitmap you should be able to load it with [CImage::Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tf4bytf8.aspx) and use it...

Comment: How do i sure this stream is a bitmap? I am using CImage::Load but some atributtes(such as m_hDc) notice that expression can't be evaluated, and m_nWidth, m_nHeight are zeros.